# Swift: Saving data with NSCoding is very slow - how to speed this up?

Tags: ios, swift, data-structures, save, nscoding

I am closely following the developer tutorial:

[Start Developing iOS Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/PersistData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH14-SW1)

And it is quite easy to understand, but saving data with `NSCoding` is very slow (after pressing the save button it takes even on the latest phones a couple of seconds!). Is there a way to speed this up?

From the `MealViewController.swift` an `unwindSegue` sends the created data to the `MealTableViewContorller.swift` where it is saved. In the `Meals.swift` file the data structure including the `NSCoding`  is created:

I just added the `NSCoding` code here so that you can see how the data is saved and maybe have a solution on how to speed this up.

Meal.swift:

```
class Meal: NSObject, NSCoding {


    //MARK: Archiving Paths
    static let DocumentsDirectory = FileManager().urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("meals")

    //MARK: Types

    struct PropertyKey {
        static let name = "name"
        static let photo = "photo"
        static let rating = "rating"
    }

    //MARK: NSCoding

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(name, forKey: PropertyKey.name)
        aCoder.encode(photo, forKey: PropertyKey.photo)
        aCoder.encode(rating, forKey: PropertyKey.rating)
    }

    required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        // The name is required. If we cannot decode a name string, the initializer should fail.
        guard let name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.name) as? String else {
            os_log("Unable to decode the name for a Meal object.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
            return nil
        }

        // Because photo is an optional property of Meal, just use conditional cast.
        let photo = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: PropertyKey.photo) as? UIImage

        let rating = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: PropertyKey.rating)

        // Must call designated initializer.
        self.init(name: name, photo: photo, rating: rating)

    }
}
```

MealTableViewController.swift:

```
private func saveMeals() {
        let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(meals, toFile: Meal.ArchiveURL.path)
        if isSuccessfulSave {
            os_log("Meals successfully saved.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        } else {
            os_log("Failed to save meals...", log: OSLog.default, type: .error)
        }
    }
```

Loading data on the other hand is very speedy.

Comment: Instead of `NSCoding` and all of the Objective-C baggage it brings, try using Swift 4's Codable and related serialization.

Comment: Any suggestions where to start? I am still new to Swift and coding and NSCoding was a pretty deep dive for me right now.

Comment: As always, start with the documentation: [Encoding, Decoding, and Serialization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/encoding_decoding_and_serialization).